# A weird contradiction in integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

Let:

$r=\sqrt{a^2+p^2-2ap \cos \theta}$

where $a,p,\theta$ are independent variables

$$\int_{a-p}^{a+p} a\ f(r) dr=\int_0^\pi a\ f(r) \dfrac{a\ p\ \sin \theta}{r} d\theta=a \int_0^\pi f(r) \dfrac{a\ p\ \sin \theta}{r} d\theta= a \int_{a-p}^{a+p} f(r) dr$$

Now I have arrived at an equation which is obviously incorrect.

$$\int_{a-p}^{a+p} a\ f(r) dr= a \int_{a-p}^{a+p} f(r) dr$$

$r$ is a function of $a$ and therefore $a$ cannot be taken outside the definite integral with respect to $r$.

Why does this contradiction arise. Am I missing anything. Please point out.

Comment: Did you take $a$ to be constant when computing $dr$? If r depends on $a$ and $\theta$ then it follows that $a$ depends on $r$  and $\theta$.

Comment: Did'nt get what you mean? Can you describe in detail in an answer?

Comment: $a,p, \theta$ are defined to be independent variables. $r(a,p,\theta)$ is a multivariable function of $a,p, \theta$. Then how can $a$ depend on $\theta$?

Comment: I mean independent variables...

Comment: When you calculate $dr$ you have treated $a$ and $p$ like constants and differentiated wrt $\theta$. Why is $\theta$ special?

Comment: $dr$ can be substituted by $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} d \theta$ OR $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial p} d p$ OR $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial a} d a$. Am I wrong? I choose the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn’t in anything you did along the way. $a$ already occurs outside the integral at the very beginning, since the limits of the integral (which contain $a$ and $p$) are also outside the integral and should contain only free variables and not the integration variables.

So the question is what you originally meant by $\int_{a-p}^{a+p}af(r)\mathrm dr$. It’s hard to make sense of this under your interpretation of $a$,$p$ and $\theta$ as independent variables on an equal footing, since we should then be integrating over three variables, not over one that is a function of the three.

You seem to be integrating over the distance $r$ on a circle of radius $a$ from a point at distance $p$ from the centre. If so, it would seem to make sense to regard either the angle $\mathrm\theta$ along the circle or the distance $r$ as free variables and the radius $a$ of the circle and the distance $p$ of the point from the centre as fixed parameters that describe the situation. Then the dependence of the integrals on $a$ and $p$ would make sense.

But that’s just a guess; the main point of the answer is that this interpretational question doesn’t come up at the end of your calculations, but already at the beginning.

Comment: tks 4 ans... I think I understand where I am being unclear.